# Hover Stylus for capacitive touchscreen

Tags: electrical-engineering, microelectronics

Capacitive touchscreens do not rely on touch as the name suggests but rather measure the distortion of the electrostatic field. To my understanding a touchscreen might be able depending on the build to detect touches from a distance of a couple of tenths of a millimeter above the surface.

Is there a way to influence the electric field of the touchscreen from a greater distance such as a centimeter above the screen?

What I am thinking is that creating an electrostatic charge might perhaps help, for example similar to the way an ionizer works. Unfortunately I lack the electrical knowledge to understand the implications of 'the other half of the capacitor' which is needed to excite the touchscreen.

The goal is to create a 'hover stylus' similar to the wacom digitizer (which of course works differently based on electromagnetic resonance).

Answer (score 0):

The Samsung Galaxy note 8 and later used a stylus with a rare earth magnet... which interferes with electrostatic fields.

Comment: It appears that the Galaxy Notw 8 with the "S Pen" uses digitizer technology from Wacom. This S Pen does most likely not hover with other touchscreen devices.